# How to use Windows environment variables in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, environment-variables, qt5

I'm working on a project, where I wanted to access a sound file from `C:/Windows/media`, but to keep it more general, I want to use some environment variable from the user's system.

This code works At the moment

```
soundURL = QUrl::fromUserInput(soundFilename,
                                       QStringLiteral("C:/Windows/media"),
                                       QUrl::AssumeLocalFile);
```

I have tried the below code, doesn't work

```
soundURL = QUrl::fromUserInput(soundFilename,
                                       QStringLiteral((%%WINDIR%%)+"/media"),
                                       QUrl::AssumeLocalFile);
```

How can I make use of %WINDIR% to make the path simpler and more general?

Comment: `(%%WINDIR%%)` is not a valid C++ expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt5 exposes several functions to retrieve the value stored in an environment variable, namely [qgetenv](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qgetenv) and [qEnvironmentVariable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qEnvironmentVariable).

As you seem to target Windows, the safer is to use `QString qEnvironmentVariable(const char *varName)`

```
QString winDirPath = qEnvironmentVariable("WINDIR");

if (!winDirPath.isNull()) {
    // the environment variable WINDIR exists and has been retrieved
} else {
    // the environment variable does not exists in this system
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path(getenv("WINDIR"));
```

will put %WINDIR% in a std::string. I would expect you can do the same with Qt types.

You're probably better off using Qt Standard Paths http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html. Messing with %WINDIR% is a bit dangerous.